# Are modules for the ring of formal power series representations of a certain object?

Tags: category-theory, modules, representation-theory, monoid, formal-power-series

Most of my exposure to modules has been over the various forms of category algebras, such as group algebras, path algebras, and incidence algebras. As such, I don't have a lot of exposure to modules over arbitrary rings. Right now, I am trying to understand modules over rings of formal power series $k[\![X]\!]$, and I'm wondering if there's a way to understand them as representations of a particular object. I know for $k[X]$ we may envision $k[X]\!\operatorname{-Mod}$ as representations of $\mathbb{N}^{|X|}$, but can we make any such claim for $k[\![X]\!]$?

<s>More precisely is there a category, $C$ such that $k[C] \cong k[\![X]\!]$? If so, does $C$ reasonably correspond to some more common combinatorial or algebraic object like a quiver or a monoid? Otherwise, why not? Is there something about $k[\![X]\!]$ that prevents this from happening?</s>

Note, I'm interested in the case of $X$ potentially being infinite, however if it is true only of finite $X$ I would be interested in hearing why.

---

Edit: relatively quickly after posting this, I realized $k[\![X]\!]$ has no non-trival idempotents, so $C$ must have a single object, so we can ignore the category theory and simply ask is their a monoid $M$ such the $k[\![X]\!] \cong k[M]$?

Comment: If you view $k[[x]]$ as completion of $k[x]$, which is the path algebra of a one-loop quiver, then $k[[x]]$ is just the completed path algebra of the one-looped quiver.  Then $k[[x]]$-modules are just graded (with the loop in degree 1) representation of the one-loop quiver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're never monoids algebras.

In the paper *Monoid rings which are valuation rings*, J. Ohm, P. Vicxnair, they mention such a theorem as a "well known result".

**Theorem** (folklore). If $k[M]$ is a valuation ring, then $k$ is a characteristic $p$ field, and $M$ is either $\Bbb Z/p^r$ or $\Bbb Z[1/p]/\Bbb Z$.

Complete proof of this statement is a bit involved, but fairly elementary, and can be found in this paper.

Formal power series are not monoid rings, because they are uncountable-dimensional valuation rings for any base field and any number of variables, while all monoids resulting in valuation rings are countable.

Comment: How difficult would you say the proof is? Should I reasonably try to work it out myself before reading it?

Comment: @tox123 It's easy, but non-obvious. You need to know a few facts which are quite easy to prove, but hard to notice: a) observation that the groups listed above are the only groups with the property that for each pair of elements $f, g$, either $f^m = g$ or $g^m = f$; b) every local monoid ring is in fact a group ring, and group rings which are local rings are $p$-group rings over a local ring with char $p$ residue field.